# how can I update hostname

Tags: debian, terminal, aws

I created AMI from AWS server instance (ip: 10.15.1.202), and created a new instance (ip: 10.15.1.117) with the AMI. 
When connecting new server, at terminal it shows wrong (previous server ip) ip like below;

[image]

I think "admin@ip-10.15.1.117" should be appear instead of "admin@ip-10.15.1.202".

I hope that I could get some explanation or help.
Thanks.

Comment: If you cloned the server, did you change the hostname? How is the hostname being generated otherwise?

Comment: What @kemotep is trying to tell: The terminal will by standard display `<user>@<hostname>` and not a variable, IP address-based value. Thus the `ip-1-2-3-4`-name is actually a fixed name and set in the system configuration instead of dynamically read from the network configuration. Check e.g. `cat /etc/hostname`. When the server was cloned, so was the name of the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating at /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts and run /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start, and then restart server, it is corrected.